# FMXTee.Import.pas(894): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Grid'

Tags: delphi, teechart, delphi-10-seattle, delphi-10.1-berlin

I tried to compile file **FMXTee.Import.pas from TeeChart 9 for XE10 Seattle** using **XE10.1 Berlin** and get error :  **[dcc32 Error] FMXTee.Import.pas(894): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Grid'** at the following syntax (in file FMXTee.Import.pas) :

```
result := .....
         {$IFDEF FMX}
         (AComponent is TImageControl) or
         ((AComponent is TColumn) and (TColumnAccess(AComponent).Grid<>nil) and (TColumnAccess(AComponent).Grid is TStringGrid)) or
         (AComponent is TTextControl)
         {$ELSE}
         (AComponent is TControl)
         {$ENDIF};
```

I think because file **FMX.Grid.pas from XE10 Seattle packages** totally different to **FMX.Grid.pas from X10.1 Berlin packages** that I don't found **Grid** property of **TColumnAccess** class.

Now, how to fix this error ?
Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you asked Steema support? You have a licensed copy of TeeChart 9, so you have free support available. (Only licensed copies come with source.)

Comment: Support is only "free" for the first 12 months.  A licensed copy doesn't necessarily mean an active *subscription* and TeeChart 9 is long in the tooth.  No telling when the license was purchased and when the OP's support expired.  Also worth noting is that (among other options) Steema explicitly point to StackOverflow on their "Support" page so it's surely not unreasonable to ask such questions here ?  (even if the answer is simply "you need to upgrade to a more current version of TeeChart", which I suspect it may be, in this case).

Comment: I think this problem not only found in TeeChart but all of others that used FMX.Grid.pas too, and file FMX.Grid.pas  has totally different from XE10 vs XE10.1 especially at TColumnAccess class in my case.

Comment: Have you tried their forums? http://www.teechart.net/support/viewforum.php?f=17&sid=7e65a95e6d38b532d09c3a34263cb5b7

Comment: And in a quick search, in less than a minute, I found this: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=16066&sid=7e65a95e6d38b532d09c3a34263cb5b7 So make sure you have the *latest* version of their code.

Comment: And finally always ask to buy the new one without give how to treat the old source in order able to run in XE10.1

Comment: @Deltics: Steema's explicitly pointing their users here is irrelevant; this has been discussed in Meta and the main Meta many times. Vendors are free to say what they want on their sites. My local restaurant could put something on their web site that says *All questions regarding our menu should be asked at SO*. The first place to ask about installation issues with a third-party component should be their support email or forums. (Which apparently would have helped, since Jerry found it in just a few minutes in those forums.)

Comment: Yes because comparing a restaurant directing questions about their menu to SO is *exactly* the same as a software component company.  FFS.  The answer in this case was fairly obvious (FMX.Grid had changed); it wasn't an installation issue.  There are any number of SO questions that arguably should be directed at vendor support; the Delphi "community" seem uniquely hung up on it.  Yes, direct an OP to the vendor, but *why not answer the question while you're at it* ?  I guess OP should count themselves lucky an MCVE wasn't demanded before anybody even *deigned* to help them even that much.

Comment: @Deltics: It's an issue installing the component into a new Delphi version. FFS back - posting to SO isn't supposed to be the *first* thing you do. A basic *check the vendor's forums* was enough for Jerry to find the information. You're not new here; you should have a grasp of the concept of posters making an effort first before posting here.

Comment: @Deltics: And I didn't say the restaurant was *the same*. I was making the point that anyone can post on their website that questions should be asked here; doing so doesn't have any meaning or relevance.